# Is Harry emotionally fit to be head Auror?

Tags: harry-potter

JKR has said that Kingsley recruits Harry as head Auror after the Battle of Hogwarts. There is no doubt Harry has the skill and determination to make a great Auror but does he have the personality?

**He is angry.**

We see throughout the series that Harry is prone to angry outbursts. This is fine when duelling but when interrogating suspects or supporting victims it isn't great.

We also see that Harry can annoy his best friend enough to temporarily abandon him. If this is the case I can imagine Harry annoying other Aurors enough to make them quit.

So we have a skilled but annoying boss who intimidates and scares suspects and victims. Not a great candidate in my opinion.

Comment: Most people mature as they grow up. We can't really judge him as an adult by his actions as a teenager.

Comment: This seems very opinion-based.

Comment: Reminds me of a certain Vader.

Comment: Umm.... Ron didn't leave because Harry annoyed him. Ron left because of his own insecurities, his dissatisfaction with how quickly the Horcrux hunt was proceeding, and the anger caused by wearing the locket. Harry's "angry outbursts" consist of shouting at his friends a few times as a teenager (confined mostly to *Order of the Phoenix*), trying to kill the person who had just murdered his godfather, and attacking a violent Death Eater who was treating a friend very poorly and had tortured students.  Honestly, this doesn't seem very different from the majority of people.

Comment: "So we have a skilled but annoying boss who intimidates and scares suspects and victims. Not a great candidate in my opinion." we've seen exactly zero scenes of Harry acting as an auror. We have zero evidence that he did any of these things to his fellow aurors. This is literally asking why someone got a promotion at their job when they had some bad days and got into arguments with people some 10+ years earlier.

Comment: also, harry wasn't immediately head of office. he was employed after the second wizard war and promoted 9 years later. so he had some time to proof himself.

Answer (score 6):

### Harry is a skilled wizard

Although he did not complete his schooling, Harry got good grades in most of his classes. His talents in Defense Against the Dark Arts were consistently exemplary, at least in classes not taught by entirely incompetent professors. He received an Outstanding on his O.W.L.s, and very likely would have received a similar grade on his N.E.W.T.s . As Professor McGonagall says:

> 'False hope?' repeated Professor McGonagall, still refusing to look
>   round at Professor
>   Umbridge. 'He has achieved high marks in all his Defence Against the
>   Dark Arts tests -'
>
> 'I'm terribly sorry to have to contradict you, Minerva, but as you
>   will see from my note, Harry 
>   has been achieving very poor results in his classes with me -'
>
> 'I should have made my meaning plainer,' said Professor McGonagall,
>   turning at last to look 
>   Umbridge directly in the eyes. 'He has achieved high marks in all
>   Defence Against the Dark 
>   Arts tests set by a competent teacher.'

### Harry has an extraordinary record of fighting Dark Magic, particularly for a boy of 17

- In his first year of school, at the age of 11, Harry stopped Lord Voldemort from obtaining the Philosopher's Stone and returning to power.
- In his second year, Harry killed a basilisk, a powerful creature of Dark Magic. He also destroyed a Horcrux.
- In his third year, though it was not widely known at the time, Harry nearly helped capture a Dark Wizard and mass murderer. He also repelled hundreds of Dementors at once.
- In his fourth year, Harry successfully escaped from Lord Voldemort, after resisting the Imperius Curse and holding him off temporarily in a duel.
- In his fifth year, Harry fought off two Dementors sent to silence him. He also continued to expose the return of Voldemort. At the end of the book, he and several friends contended with a dozen Death Eaters and held them off long enough for Dumbledore to intervene. The conclusion of this battle showed him resisting possession by Lord Voldemort.
- In the his sixth year, Harry helped overcome several traps set by Voldemort to protect his Horcruxes.
- In what would have been his seventh year, Harry:

  - Destroyed all of Voldemorts remaining Horcruxes (mostly by proxy)
  - Stayed on the run from the Ministry and Death Eaters for nearly a year.
  - Escaped from Voldemort's base at Malfoy Manor.
  - Escaped Voldemort's attempted ambush upon leaving Privet Drive, and shattered his wand.
  - Fought Voldemort at the Battle of Hogwarts.
  - Broke into Gringotts while it was under Death Eater control.
  - Fought Death Eaters in the Battle of Hogwarts
  - Defeated and killed Voldemort himself.

**With a record like this, and test results to back it up, frankly, it wouldn't matter how abrasive Harry was.**

But...

### Harry is actually quite emotionally mature

He was brave enough to fight the most powerful and evil person of his time, and not to back down even when it seemed it would mean his death.

He was humble enough to master the Hallows, and disavowed any responsibility for his successes.

> 'Listen to me!' said Harry, almost angrily, because Ron and Hermione
>   were both smirking now. 'Just listen to me, all right? It sounds great
>   when you say it like that, but all that stuff was luck - I didn't know
>   what I was doing half the time,  I didn't plan any of it, I just did
>   whatever I could think of, and I nearly always had help -'

He was able to forgive people who had harmed him, such as Xenophilius Lovegood and Draco Malfoy, even offering Voldemort a chance to redeem himself.

He had some arguments with his friends, certainly. There are a handful of times across several years in which he had such disputes. But this is not extraordinary. When I was fifteen, I can guarantee I argued with my parents far more than a few times a year. That the worst arguments Harry got in were mostly shouting matches, and fairly infrequent, actually reflects well on him.

He tried to kill Bellatrix Lestrange in a fit of rage. Well, she had just killed his godfather. Many people would have felt exactly the same way. It is worth noting that he was able to overcome his anger toward Snape, Malfoy, Dumbledore and even Voldemort, some time later.

**Harry is emotionally at least as mature as the average teenager subjected to high-stress conditions (i.e. a war).**

**Harry is a highly skilled wizard, with an extraordinary list of accomplishments. The real question is this: Why wouldn't the Ministry hire him as Head Auror right away?**

Answer (score 1):

Harry's outbursts were caused by Voldemort. They don't reflect Harry's mood. The outbursts started in GoF or OotP, a point of time in which Voldemort's strength, and with it the bond between Harry and Voldemort, grew.

The first fallout in the Trio was in PoA, caused by Scabbers vanishing. This fallout was between Ron and Hermione, so Harry was in an awkward position. This was not his fault.

Another one was between Ron and Harry in GoF, after Harry was chosen as champion. Ron was jealous because Harry had found a way to get his name into the goblet. This wasn't done by Harry, but by Barty Crouch Jr., so not Harry's fault.

The next one was in GoF, again caused by Ron and Hermione because of Hermione's behavior towards Viktor Krum. Once again, not Harry's fault.

I can't remember any bigger quarrels in the Trio besides the one in DH, which can be blamed on the Horcrux, that was worn by Harry in the moment Ron and he started to argue.

Besides those big ones, there were also some minor ones, which didn't bear any consequences of significance.

About Harry lashing out, well, it can be blamed on Voldemort. Harry's outbursts of emotions were mainly in OotP, the installment with the biggest bond between Voldemort's and Harry's emotions, and DH, the one with the Horcrux. Also, in OotP, Harry does not only have sudden outbursts of anger, but also of happiness, strengthening this hypothesis.